# Deleted Unique Constraint in MongoDB create again with same name

Tags: node.js, mongodb

During starting my project some how i define modal as unique in mongoose
let Say:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    categoryName: { type: String, Unique: true},
    discription:String
});
```

After some day a situation comes and i delete Unique key now my model is:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
        categoryName:String,,
        discription:String
    });
```

Now the real Problem is that when i publish  and document inserted it still creates indexes of  categoryName.

Want to know why this still create and how to recover from these error on production.

Comment: Yes. Because Index is still exists in MongoDB. Just removing from mongoose model does not delete unique index from DB. You have to drop index.

Comment: @hiren  Droping index each time is not a permanent solution any other option available for the same that reset index before going live

Comment: mongoose.connections[0].collections("collectionname").dropIndex("propertyName",callback)

Comment: I don't think people usually assign and remove drop indexes frequently. In Development, you can call above code if you want to remove.

Comment: @hiren You are right indexes are not assigned and removed frequently. But the problem is that when a developer create indexes once they are not able to remove permanently and they spend time on removing indexes. It require an option there is contastraint delete it delete the references for the same.